# TSQL Recursive Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables in my tool that I am working with.

One is an employee database, another is a table that contains a count of the number of direct reports each person with directs has.

Here are the sample tables I have set up:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0b414/3

Here is a sample query I am working on. However, what I need to do is Insert a record into another table with the count of directs each person has.

If they don't have a direct, they don't get added into the table.

```
;WITH employees_CTE (FirstName, LastName, QID, Email, SupQID, Title) AS
    (
        SELECT      FirstName,
                    LastName,
                    QID,
                    Email,
                    SupQID,
                    Title
        FROM        employees E
        WHERE       QID = 'Q12345'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT      E.FirstName,
                    E.LastName,
                    E.QID,
                    E.Email,
                    E.SupQID,
                    E.Title
        FROM        employees E
        INNER JOIN  employees_CTE AS E2 ON E.SupQID = E2.QID
        --Some type of INSERT statement here if the number of people reporting to you are greater than zero.
    )
```

The CTE is about as far as I was able to get with it. I am stuck on figuring out how to get the count from within the CTE so I known whether or not to insert it into table2.

A direct report is where someone's SupQID is your own. That supQID field is the supervisor(direct) of the employee.

Any ideas?

EDIT: The reason for needing to do this recursively rather than by join is to save space: Not all departments are in need of this sort of tracking, and being able to say "Anyone who reports up through X" leaves options open to opening it up in the future, or adding departments, if there's ever a need to.

Comment: The SQL Fiddle is nice, but you could at least set it up so the field names match your example query.

Comment: Sorry, fixed: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ff315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our [chat regarding the reason to want to do this recursively](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62497/sbbs-recursive-spec), the main issue you have is no Aggregate functions in the recursive portion of the query.

As such, you can arrive at your results by doing one more join when you select from the CTE, like so:

```
;WITH employees_CTE (First, Last, QID, Email, Supervisor, Title) AS
    (
        SELECT      First,
                    Last,
                    QID,
                    Email,
                    Supervisor,
                    Title
        FROM        employees E
        WHERE       QID IN ( 'Q24285', 'Q07341' )

        UNION ALL

        SELECT      E.First,
                    E.Last,
                    E.QID,
                    E.Email,
                    E.Supervisor,
                    E.Title
        FROM        employees E
        INNER JOIN  employees_CTE AS E2 ON E.Supervisor = E2.QID
      
        --Some type of INSERT statement here if the number of people reporting to you are greater than zero.
    )
SELECT C.First, C.Last, C.QID, C.EMAIL, C.Supervisor, C.Title, COUNT(DISTINCT E.QID) AS CountOfDirects
FROM employees_CTE C
  INNER JOIN Employees E ON E.Supervisor = C.QID
GROUP BY C.First, C.Last, C.QID, C.EMAIL, C.Supervisor, C.Title
;
```

See the results on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0b414/46).

This provides a framework which can be easily adapted to your needs. You can wrap a procedure declaration about this and feed in the QID you want to capture as a parameter, then just add the insert statement as part of the final select statement and you're golden.

Comment: Any chance you want to include the link to the chat?  The opening comment is confusing because no one will understand the reference.

Comment: Done. Took a bit for me to find where to get to it again.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select  E.Title,COUNT(*) CountofDirects,E.First,E.Last from Employees E
JOIN Employees EE
ON E.QID=EE.Supervisor
GROUP BY E.Title,E.First,E.Last
```

with insert into

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2(Title,CountofDirects,First,Last)
select  E.Title,COUNT(*) CountofDirects,E.First,E.Last from Employees E
JOIN Employees EE
ON E.QID=EE.Supervisor
GROUP BY E.Title,E.First,E.Last
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0b414/28)

Comment: So the fiddle looks right as far as the number of directs go; but I am a little confused about your other 2 queries. Is it possible to add the insert into your fiddle? I have the table2 structure set up there already.

Comment: Not Understood `count of directs each person has`.Did you mean `count of directors` ??

Comment: I provide a query by `Insert a record into another table with the count of directs(count took from table2 based on QID) each person has`

Comment: Sorry, I dont think you understand the question. Pretend the data in table2 doesn't exist yet. I need to loop over the `employees` table and count the number of people each person has that reports to them. Example: The President has 1 person reporting to them, the VP. It would insert a 1 as the count into table2. Next, the VP has 3 managers reporting to them so the VP's `QID' would get inserted into table2 with a 3 for the count.

Comment: @SBB changed you can check now

Comment: Still not what I am looking for. Thanks though!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62493/discussion-between-sbb-and-ganesh-devlekar).

Comment: How will your query work when I give it a starting point? I only want to get people that are direct reports of the president so when I add `
WHERE E.QID = 'Q12345'` it only gives me that persons report, not everyone under them.